# How to remove the hint in the terminal?

Tags: centos, netstat, ps, stderr

As a normal user , when I run some command like ps\netstat, the terminal hint me:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

I know could redirect STDERR to /dev/null can remove this hint. But I want to know is there any way to remove it , such as edit some configuration files ?

```
[deploy@storage2 ~]$ ps -V
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
procps version 3.2.7

[deploy@storage2 ~]$ ps -V 2>/dev/null
procps version 3.2.7
```

My OS info:

```
[deploy@storage2 ~]$ uname -a
Linux storage2 2.6.18-243.el5 #1 SMP Mon Feb 7 18:47:27 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64         GNU/Linux

[deploy@storage2 ~]$ lsb_release 
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch

[deploy@storage2 ~]$ netstat -V
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
net-tools 1.60
netstat 1.42 (2001-04-15)
Fred Baumgarten, Alan Cox, Bernd Eckenfels, Phil Blundell, Tuan Hoang and others
+NEW_ADDRT +RTF_IRTT +RTF_REJECT +FW_MASQUERADE +I18N
AF: (inet) +UNIX +INET +INET6 +IPX +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +ATALK +ECONET +ROSE 
HW:  +ETHER +ARC +SLIP +PPP +TUNNEL +TR +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +FR +ROSE +ASH +SIT +FDDI         +HIPPI +HDLC/LAPB
```

There are more info from strace:

```
[deploy@storage2 ~]$ strace ps -V
execve("/bin/ps", ["ps", "-V"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x929a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99752, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 99752, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fde000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0 \241\210\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=101404, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fdd000
mmap2(0x887000, 92104, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x887000
mmap2(0x89a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12) = 0x89a000
mmap2(0x89c000, 6088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x89c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0Pzt\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=16428, ...}) = 0
mmap2(0x747000, 12408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x747000
mmap2(0x749000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0x749000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\20\204p\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=208352, ...}) = 0
mmap2(0x705000, 155760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x705000
mmap2(0x72a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24) = 0x72a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\340\246q\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=45288, ...}) = 0
mmap2(0x71a000, 201020, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fab000
mmap2(0xf7fb4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8) = 0xfffffffff7fb4000
mmap2(0xf7fb6000, 155964, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fb6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0 \n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=13420, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 12428, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fa7000
mmap2(0xf7fa9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0xfffffffff7fa9000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0@(s\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=129716, ...}) = 0
mmap2(0x72e000, 90596, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x72e000
mmap2(0x741000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13) = 0x741000
mmap2(0x743000, 4580, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x743000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\340?]\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1611564, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fa6000
mmap2(0x5be000, 1328580, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x5be000
mmap2(0x6fd000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13f) = 0x6fd000
mmap2(0x700000, 9668, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x700000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fa5000
set_thread_area(0xffd61bb4)             = 0
mprotect(0x6fd000, 8192, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x741000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0xf7fa9000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7fb4000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x72a000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x749000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x89a000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x5ba000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
munmap(0xf7fde000, 99752)               = 0
set_tid_address(0xf7fa5708)             = 20214
set_robust_list(0xf7fa5710, 0xc)        = 0
futex(0xffd61f74, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x4007323d0, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x10000004007322e0, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=-4284481536, rlim_max=67108864*1024}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="storage2", ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/bin/ps"..., 260) = 7
brk(0)                                  = 0x929a000
brk(0x92bb000)                          = 0x92bb000
open("/bin/ps", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)   = 3
_llseek(3, -12, [711660], SEEK_END)     = 0
read(3, "\274U!\253\2\0\0\0\224\237\t\0", 12) = 12
mmap2(NULL, 634880, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0x13) = 0xfffffffff7f0a000
mmap2(NULL, 630784, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7e70000
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x74a06c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
geteuid32()                             = 501
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl64(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl64(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1696, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7ff6000
read(3, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1696
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xf7ff6000, 4096)                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99752, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 99752, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7fde000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\300\30\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=46680, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 41616, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7e65000
mmap2(0xf7e6e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8) = 0xfffffffff7e6e000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0xf7e6e000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xf7fde000, 99752)               = 0
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2166, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7ff6000
read(3, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 2166
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xf7ff6000, 4096)                = 0
mkdir("/tmp/pdk-deploy/", 0755)         = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdir("/tmp/pdk-deploy/fcb734befe617ec3ae1edc38da810a5a", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
open("/tmp/pdk-deploy/fcb734befe617ec3ae1edc38da810a5a/libperl.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/tmp/pdk-deploy/fcb734befe617ec3ae1edc38da810a5a/libperl.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\300!\2\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=1264090, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1140104, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7d4e000
mmap2(0xf7e5a000, 45056, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10b) = 0xfffffffff7e5a000
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {0x1000000000000001, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND|SA_SIGINFO|0x3d61cb8, (nil)}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL ABRT BUS SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU XCPU WINCH IO PWR SYS RTMIN RT_1 RT_2 RT_4 RT_5 RT_8 RT_9 RT_11 RT_12 RT_13 RT_16 RT_17 RT_18 RT_22 RT_24 RT_25 RT_26 RT_27 RT_28 RT_29 RT_30 RT_31], SA_RESTART|SA_RESETHAND|0x22302d0}, 8) = 0
getuid32()                              = 501
geteuid32()                             = 501
getgid32()                              = 502
getegid32()                             = 502
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56454896, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7b4e000
mmap2(NULL, 241664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x13ec) = 0xfffffffff7b13000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x1466) = 0xfffffffff7b12000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7af1000
time(NULL)                              = 1348210009
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/bin/ps"..., 4095) = 7
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
_llseek(0, 0, 0xffd618d0, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd618a8) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
_llseek(1, 0, 0xffd618d0, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd618a8) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
_llseek(2, 0, 0xffd618d0, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd61978) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(3, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTART|SA_RESETHAND|0x22302d0}, 8) = 0
brk(0x92dc000)                          = 0x92dc000
getppid()                               = 20212
stat64("/opt/ActivePerl-5.8/site/lib/sitecustomize.pl", 0xffd61560) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/.khostd/.hostconf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd61828) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(3, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=334, ...}) = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
read(3, "bindport=9001\ntrustip=221.122.57"..., 4096) = 334
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0) = 20215
close(6)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(5, "", 4)                          = 0
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd61868) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
_llseek(3, 0, 0xffd61890, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
"tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001"..., 4096) = 109
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x1, [], SA_STACK|0x129b3d8}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_RESTART|SA_RESETHAND|0x22302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x1, [], SA_STACK|0x129b3d8}, {SIG_DFL, [TRAP BUS FPE USR1 CHLD CONT TTOU VTALRM IO RTMIN], SA_RESTART|SA_RESETHAND|0x22302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x1, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_RESTART|SA_RESETHAND|0x22302d0}, 8) = 0
waitpid(20215, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0) = 20215
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [TRAP BUS FPE USR1 CHLD CONT TTOU VTALRM IO RTMIN], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
chdir("/usr/lib/.khostd")               = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0) = 20218
close(6)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(5, "", 4)                          = 0
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd61868) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
_llseek(3, 0, 0xffd61890, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND|0x3d61850, (nil)}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x1, [], SA_STACK|0x129b3d8}, {SIG_DFL, [HUP INT], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x1, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, 8) = 0
waitpid(20218, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0) = 20218
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [HUP INT], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
chdir("/home/deploy")                   = 0
stat64("/etc/cron.hourly/hichina", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=711660, ...}) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0) = 20230
close(6)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(5, "", 4)                          = 0
close(5)                                = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xffd61868) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
_llseek(3, 0, 0xffd61890, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(3, "procps version 3.2.7\n", 4096) = 21
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x1, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_STACK|SA_RESTART|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND|0x3d61850, (nil)}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x1, [], SA_STACK|0x129b3d8}, {SIG_DFL, [HUP INT], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x1, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, 8) = 0
waitpid(20230, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0) = 20230
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [HUP INT], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, ~[HUP INT ILL TRAP KILL SEGV ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD TSTP TTOU RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_6 RT_9 RT_11 RT_14 RT_15 RT_16 RT_17 RT_20 RT_22], SA_NOCLDSTOP|SA_NOCLDWAIT}, NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "procps version 3.2.7\n", 21procps version 3.2.7
)  = 21
munmap(0xf7af1000, 135168)              = 0
munmap(0xf7e70000, 630784)              = 0
munmap(0xf7f0a000, 634880)              = 0
munmap(0xf7d4e000, 1140104)             = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
[ Process PID=20214 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
```

Thank you very much.

**SOLVED:**
  Download procps source code, and rebuilt it, the hints disapperaed.

Comment: How about this `\ps -V`?

Comment: Got the hint still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running on EL5 right? I have an EL5 box here and it gives me:

```
$ ps -V
procps version 3.2.7
```

No hint. `/bin/ps` is in the `procps` package, which has no configuration files.

Further: something weird is going on on your machine. I don't have the time to really dive into this (so maybe this is expected behaviour in your environment), but what's with all the Perl related things in our strace output? `ps` is not Perl related, so why do I see all kinds of Perl related (ActivePerl, pdk-deploy, etc.) things in your strace output? Either it is polluted, by some weird construction in your .bashrc, or you have aliases for `ps` et al. that mess things up, or somebody is playing a trick on you.

Comment: Yes, it's EL5. ps is /bin/ps, and there is no alias related with ps. I 've grep ~/.bashrc,/etc/profile,/etc/profile.d/*, and ps does not appear. This is a xen box, and I think the HiChina had modifed the source code of linux and rebuild it. This can explain why perl apperas in the strace's output, and string hichina appears in the output too.

Comment: It appears as a cronjob. Why is a cronjob listed in the strace output of `ps`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the /etc/cron.hourly/hichina is and for. I've donwnload procps's source code, and build it. Then the hints disappered. Thanks very much.

Comment: I still think there is more going on. I have a weird feeling about this. (And you can accept my answer if it works for you ;))